# Small compiled Typescript code provided from TS documentation crashes

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, typescript2.0

I've been following Typescript's Handbook but script crashes on the code example that you can find here:

> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties

Can anyone help me resolving this issue?

```
{
    class BeeKeeper {
        hasMask: boolean;
    }
    class ZooKeeper {
        nametag: string;
    }
    class Animal {
        numLegs: number;
    }
    class Bee extends Animal {
        keeper: BeeKeeper;
    }
    class Lion extends Animal {
        keeper: ZooKeeper;
    }
    function createInstance<A extends Animal>(c: new () => A): A {
        return new c();
    }
    createInstance(Lion).keeper.nametag;  // typechecks!
//  createInstance(Lion).keeper.hasMask;  // error!
    createInstance(Bee).keeper.hasMask;   // typechecks!
}
```

This is the code block compiled in TS:

```
{
    var createInstance = function createInstance(c) {
        return new c();
    };
    var BeeKeeper = function BeeKeeper() {
        _classCallCheck(this, BeeKeeper);
    };
    var ZooKeeper = function ZooKeeper() {
        _classCallCheck(this, ZooKeeper);
    };
    var _Animal12 = function _Animal12() {
        _classCallCheck(this, _Animal12);
    };
    var Bee = function (_Animal13) {
        _inherits(Bee, _Animal13);
        function Bee() {
            _classCallCheck(this, Bee);
            return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (Bee.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Bee)).apply(this, arguments));
        }
        return Bee;
    }(_Animal12);
    var Lion = function (_Animal14) {
        _inherits(Lion, _Animal14);
        function Lion() {
            _classCallCheck(this, Lion);
            return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (Lion.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Lion)).apply(this, arguments));
        }
        return Lion;
    }(_Animal12);

    createInstance(Lion).keeper.nametag; // typechecks! <- THIS CRASHES
//    createInstance(Lion).keeper.hasMask;  // error!
    createInstance(Bee).keeper.hasMask; // typechecks!
}
```

And this is also the error's stack:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nametag' of undefined
    at Object.2../greet (main.ts:1451)
    at s (_prelude.js:1)
    at e (_prelude.js:1)
    at _prelude.js:1
```

Comment: I don't see anything assigning to `keeper` anywhere, so it will have its default value of `undefined` (or not exist at all, in which case reading its value will give you `undefined` as well). So it's not a surprise that trying to read `.nametag` from `undefined` causes that error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So I am supposed to consider this as a normal behaviour from TS?

Comment: With the code as shown, yes. The code is relying on an uninitalized property being initialized. Nothing to do with TypeScript, it's just erroneous/incomplete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample is intended to show typing behavior and is not a full runnable program. The problem you are getting is caused by the fact that the `keeper` field is not initialized in the class. To get it to run try the following:

```
class Bee extends Animal {
    keeper: BeeKeeper = new BeeKeeper();
}
class Lion extends Animal {
    keeper: ZooKeeper = new ZooKeeper();
}
```

Comment: It worked.
Of course there wasn't any initialization or constructor call so It is supposed to be initialized implicitly with keyword `new`